# What are the differences between Story Mode and Speedrun Mode?

Tags: rabi-ribi

I've played through Rabi-Ribi a couple of times in various difficulties with various objectives. I was planning to attempt getting the Speedrun achievements next by completing the game in Casual Alternative mode and then starting a New Game+ to attempt the actual speedrun in Loop 2 (as suggested in [the comments on this page](https://rabidb.com/Achievement/Detail/806)).

A few minutes into the game, I started wondering if I should have started it in Speedrun Mode rather than Story Mode, mostly to make my save files easier to identify. This raised the question: **Is there any major gameplay difference between the to modes?**

I've only looked into speedrun mode for a short amount of time, and so far the only differences I noticed are that it auto-skips cutscenes and displays a timer and keeps track of your completion stats at the top of the screen. Does anything else change, or does this mode only make things more convenient for speedrunners?

What I'd like to know is if I can still get regular achievements in speedrun mode, and if I can keep playing it after the post game is completed (to start a New Game+, among other things).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing a 100% run in Speedrun (Alternative) Mode, I have spotted the following differences:

- There's a display at the top of the screen that keeps track of your playtime, as well as map / item completion
- The game starts at the Prologue title card (the entire intro sequence is skipped)
- All dialogues and cutscenes are skipped automatically

  - If a skipped dialogue contains a choice prompt (i.e. the buffs in town), the game assumes you'd choose yes (which means that talking to Keke Bunny in order to officially recruit her forces you to go back to Plurkwood)
- The NPC in Rabi Rabi Park isn't there, so you can't change difficulty mid-game

  - However, she does appear after finishing the entire game to let you start a New Game+

Other than that, everything's pretty much the same. After the end credits, the timer keeps going and you can keep playing, just like in regular story mode.